# Detect Wicket user inactivity

Tags: wicket, user-activity

Does anybody have an idea on how I can accomplish this using Wicket?

I want to display a Wicket odal window automatically when no user activity has been detected for a certain amount of time. I'm thinking of using an AjaxSelfUpdatingBehavior in some way, but I have no clear ideas actually.

Is this possible with Wicket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can use some js library not to catch all ajax calls and to be sure, that your user is really afk (even does not touching his mouse).

For example, see [this](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js) free framework and it's [demo](http://serkanyersen.github.io/ifvisible.js/demo.html).

And (if you using this js framework) in wicket you must handle

```
ifvisible.idle(function(){
    Wicket.Ajax.get({u: '${callbackUrl}'})// This code will work when page goes into idle status
});
```

You must set ${callbackUrl} from wicket code to let js know what action to proceed in java code. It is not hard to do this. Look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Calling+Wicket+from+Javascript).

This approach is more tricky, but if you implement this, you don't have to worry about users actions at all (he can read site's info and don't click any ajax links, but suddenly he will see modal window).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I use this as autologout function

```
public class MyTimer extends AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior {

    public MyTimer(int seconds) {
        this(Duration.seconds(seconds));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
         // show your window magic
    }
}
```

Add this to you page (`add(new MyTimer(300));`) and this will be called after the number of seconds you specify. Make sure to replace the timer with a new one when doing ajax calls, or reset it.

Comment: Thank you! You say you replace the timer when doing ajax-calls. How do you do that?

Comment: I think, that you can store your 'MyTimer' instance at page as a variable, and in every ajax call, processed in your page (via AjaxLink, AjaxBehavior, etc), call myTimer.restart ( AjaxRequestTarget ) not to create another instance of the timer.